# This a code of DFS traversal two piece of code are same but one is giving segmentation fault and another is running well why?

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search, traversal

```
void dfs(int row,int col,vector<vector<int>>& vis,vector<vector<char>>& mat,int delrow[],int delcol[]){

    // giving segmentation fault

        // vis[row][col] = 1;

        // int n = mat.size();
        // int m = mat[0].size();

        // for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        //     int nrow = row + delrow[i];
        //     int ncol = col + delcol[i];

        //     if(!vis[nrow][ncol] && nrow>=0 && nrow<n && ncol>=0 && ncol<m 
        //     && mat[nrow][ncol] =='O'){
        //         dfs(nrow,ncol,vis,mat,delrow,delcol);
        //     }
        // }
```

// this code is running well

```
    vis[row][col] = 1; 
    int n = mat.size();
    int m = mat[0].size();
    
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++) {
        int nrow = row + delrow[i];
        int ncol = col + delcol[i]; 
        if(nrow >=0 && nrow <n && ncol >= 0 && ncol < m 
        && !vis[nrow][ncol] && mat[nrow][ncol] == 'O') {
            dfs(nrow, ncol, vis, mat, delrow, delcol); 
        }
    }
}
```

I have written the first code and it's giving segmentation fault

Comment: Do not tag `dsa`.  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  What you should have done is tag the language you are using, which is `C++`.  By not tagging the language, your question was totally missed by people who subscribe to the C++ tag.  Having said this, prepare for comments such as the lack of a [mcve], no debugging effort being mentioned, etc.

Comment: You are doing the `!vis[nrow][ncol]` test before testing if `nrow` and `ncol` are within range for `vis`.